# Error while deploying Adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maven-3, mobilefirst-adapters

To create a Adapter Maven project

New-->project-->Maven-->Maven Project

Then to include the Archtype

Configure → Add Local Catalog → Browse to the /.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml in the home directory.

Then to Add Archetype:

```
Archetype Group Id: com.ibm.mfp
Archetype Artifact Id:adapter-maven-archetype-http 
Archetype Version: 8.0.2016061011
```

Then For Building Adapter

Right clicked the project-->Run as--> Maven install

I console I receive BUILD SUCCESS

Then for deploying Adapter

Right clicked the project -->Run as-->Maven Build

But I received error as

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Mobile:sampleAdapter:adapter:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 44, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sampleAdapter 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.970 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-22T11:20:42+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Maven". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

With this I include the archetype-catalog.xml file 
(I created this file and pasted to the /.m2/repository)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <archetype-catalog      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd"
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<archetypes>
<archetype>
<groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
<artifactId>adapter-maven-archetype-http</artifactId>
<version>8.0.2016061011</version>
  <repository>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mfp/adapter-maven-archetype-http</repository>
</archetype>
    <archetype>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
<artifactId>adapter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.0.2016082422</version>
      <repository>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mfp/adapter-maven-plugin</repository>
 </archetype>
 </archetypes>
 </archetype-catalog>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing here... provide step-by-step reproduction steps.

Comment: In Short I am unable deploy my adapter in Eclipse IDE.https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/developing-adapters/ .According to this document I built the adapter successfully ,But while deploying I got error

Comment: Again, and not in short, edit the questions with full reproduction steps and a download of your adapter for debugging.

Comment: @Idan Now I edited my Question .Please check it out and help me

Comment: Is it done? if yes then please share the steps. I am not event able to create the project structure properly. Everytime it is displaying the error.
eclipse error Unable to create project from archetype [com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-archetype-java:8.0.2016082422] The defined artifact is not an archetype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not performing the deploy phase correctly.
See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/developing-adapters/#deploying-an-adapter

> To deploy an adapter, first add the deploy Maven command:
>
> Select Run → Run Configurations..., right-click on Maven Build and select New.
>   Provide a Name: "Maven deploy".
>   Set as a Goal: "adapter:deploy".
>   Click Apply followed by clicking on Run to have an initial deploy.
>
> You can now right-click on the adapter folder and select Run As → Maven Deploy